# PHPStorm 6 and Symfony 2 Wrong code completions

Tags: symfony, phpstorm

I'm having a problem with PHPStorm with Symfony 2.2

I have the framework setting set to Symfony2. In a controller when I type

```
use Request
```

The only two suggestions are:

```
Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request
Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Tests\Request
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Just tested with PHPStorm 6 and latest symfony and works fine. Maybe you have some other error in your controller that's putting off the autocomplete?

Comment: @Tuxdude and others, it's not off-topic, read the FAQ again and stop closing valid questions (**software tools commonly used by programmers**).

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me why this was closed, however: With PHPStorm you need to make sure your vendors folder is in the project route, you've run composer install/update. All of the namespaces should auto complete properly if the code is there (it works for me).